# autocomplete for test.py like git <tab>

Tags: python, bash

when I issue git with tab , it can auto-complete with a list, I want to write a test.py, when I type test.py followed with tab, it can auto-complete with a given list defined in test.py, is it possible ?

```
$ git [tab]  
add                 branch              column              fetch               help                mv                  reflog              revert              stash               
am                  bundle              commit              filter-branch       imap-send           name-rev            relink              rm                  status              
annotate            checkout            config              format-patch        init                notes               remote              send-email          submodule           
apply               cherry              credential          fsck                instaweb            p4                  repack              shortlog            subtree             
archive             cherry-pick         describe            gc                  log                 pull                replace             show                tag                 
bisect              clean               diff                get-tar-commit-id   merge               push                request-pull        show-branch         whatchanged         
blame               clone               difftool            grep                mergetool           rebase              reset               stage
```

Comment: If you are trying to do this inside your Python IDE, then no, I believe not. The closest you will get is if you use a git python library that will give you the supported commands that are the equivalent of executing those git commands.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do a custom `complete` script, but it would certainly be the most painful thing you'd ever coded.

Comment: I know it's not the same thing, but have you seen the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module? it has a similar function.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is: `readline.set_completer` . This method interacts with the `readline` of the bash shell. It's simple to implement. Examples: https://pymotw.com/2/readline/

Comment: I did not know of this module. It seems powerful and useful.

Comment: That's not what OP is looking for - this can have an effect only when you run your Python script, but it will not provide any sort of auto-completion on the command line itself.

Comment: It's the closest we can do from the Python environment - (lest the bash itself be implemented in Python). The workaround you mentioned, though correct, is a little convoluted considering the number of files to be altered. Rather, start a python console and leverage `readline`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a feature of the `git` binary itself, it's a `bash` completion 'hack' and as such has nothing to do with Python *per-se*, but since you've tagged it as such let's add a little twist. Let's say we create a script aware of its acceptable arguments - `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# let's define some sample functions to be called on passed arguments
def f1():
    print("F1 called!")

def f2():
    print("F2 called!")

def f3():
    print("F3 called!")

def f_invalid():  # a simple invalid placeholder function
    print("Invalid command!")

def f_list():  # a function to list all valid arguments
    print(" ".join(sorted(arguments.keys())))

if __name__ == "__main__":  # make sure we're running this as a script
    arguments = {  # a simple argument map, use argparse or similar in a real world use
        "arg1": f1,
        "arg2": f2,
        "arg3": f3,
        "list_arguments": f_list
    }
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]:  # loop through all arguments
            arguments.get(arg, f_invalid)()  # call the mapped or invalid function
    else:
        print("At least one argument required!")
```

*NOTE: Make sure you add an executable flag to the script (`chmod +x test.py`) so its shebang is used for executing instead of providing it as an argument to the Python interpreter.*

Apart from all the boilerplate, the important *argument* is `list_arguments` - it lists all available arguments to this script and we'll use this output in our `bash` completion script to instruct `bash` how to auto-complete. To do so, create another script, let's call it `test-completion.bash`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SCRIPT_NAME=test.py
SCRIPT_PATH=/path/to/your/script
_complete_script()
{
    local cursor options
    options=$(${SCRIPT_PATH}/${SCRIPT_NAME} list_arguments)
    cursor="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options}" -- ${cursor}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _complete_script ${SCRIPT_NAME}
```

What it does is essentially adding to `complete` the `_complete_script` function to be called whenever a completion over `test.py` is invoked. The `_complete_script` function itself first calls `list_arguments` on `test.py` to retrieve its acceptable arguments, and then uses `compgen` to create a required structure for `complete` to be able to print it out.

To test, all you need is to source this script as:

```
source test-completion.bash
```

And then your bash will behave as:

```
$ ./test.py [tab]
arg1            arg2            arg3            list_arguments
```

And what's more, it's completely controllable from your Python script - whatever gets printed as a list on `list_arguments` *command* is what will be shown as auto-completion help.

To make the change permanent, you can simply add the `source` line to your `.bashrc`, or if you want more structured solution you can follow the guidelines for your OS. There are a couple of ways described on the [`git-flow-completion`](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion) page for example. Of course, this assumes you actually have bash-autocomplete installed and enabled on your system, but your `git` autocompletion wouldn't work if you didn't.

Speaking of `git` autocompletion, you can see how it's implemented by checking [`git-completion.bash` source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) - a word of warning, it's not for the fainthearted.